# Bash Advanced grep solution

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I have a file.txt on my Linux which looks like the following structure:

file.txt:

```
full name
E-mail: email@email.com
Phone: 0123456789

full name
email@email.com
01/23456789

full name
e: email@email.com
00-223-445-56
.
.
.
etc
```

Or only the name entry and phone number or e-mail address

I would like to use grep to when I start

```
./myprogram.sh file.txt
```

list all of the E-mail addresses and Phone numbers from the file. How can I do that if the file.txt looks like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can start wit something simple like that:

```
cat file.txt | grep -E "(@|[0-9]+)"
```

it gives you everything with an @ (so emails) and everything with numbers (so phone numbers). you can use more advanced regular expressions for better search (emails and phone numbers do have stricter rules...) but thats the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
egrep "@|[0-9]"
```

will match only lines that contain an "@" or at least one digit. Your example says that the name line does not contain digits.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't quite clear which format you expect as an output. If you want to have e-mail addresses and phone numbers separated (is it that what you want? The connection: e-mail address <-> phone number would be kind of confused then) you could also use (GNU) sed:

```
sed -n -e '1 {s/\(.*\)/e-mail:\n\1/; P;};' \
       -e '/@/ s/\(.\+[ \\\t]\)\{0,1\}\(.\+\)@\(.\+\)/\t\2\@\3/p;' \          
       -e '/[0-9]\+$/ H; $ {x; s/\n\([^0-9]*\)\([0-9]\+\)/\n\t\2/g; s/\(.*\)/\nphone:\n\1/p;}'
       file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually want to use `grep`, or are you just using the phrase "use grep" to mean "filter".  Assuming the latter (since `grep` is the wrong tool for this), and assuming that each record has a single email address in the final column of the 2nd line and a phone number in the final column of the 3rd line, and that each record is separated by a line with no extra whitespace, you could do:

```
 <file.txt awk '{print $NF}' | awk '{print $2,$3}' FS='\n' RS=
```

You could do it with a single awk invocation, but this is simpler and probably sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

That's a job for awk, not grep:

```
$ awk '(NR%4)~/^[23]$/{print $NF}' file
email@email.com
0123456789
email@email.com
01/23456789
email@email.com
00-223-445-56

$ awk '(NR%4)~/^[23]$/{printf "%s%s", $NF, (++c%2?OFS:ORS)}' file
email@email.com 0123456789
email@email.com 01/23456789
email@email.com 00-223-445-56

$ awk '(NR%4)==2{print $NF}' file
email@email.com
email@email.com
email@email.com

$ awk '(NR%4)==3{print $NF}' file
0123456789
01/23456789
00-223-445-56
```

Take your pick, it's all trivial...